# C3270 on MAC select text

Tags: mainframe

I am using c3270 on Mac to connect to mainframe 3270. Everything works but I am not able to select any text using keyboard or mouse (except cmd+a). Can you please help me to enable select text option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to select a line and copy the text. But c3270 is not allowing me to select the text either with mouse or keyboard shift + arrows